# Creating a React Element from another Element is valid in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

somewhere i saw a code that was like this :-

```
var App = <div> Hello World </div>;
ReactDOM.render(<App />, <selector>)
```

and it was working fine, but i did not understand what is happening here ?
the first line will be converted to

```
var App = React.createElement("div", null, "Hello World");
```

and `<App />` will convert to

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, null), <selector>);
```

?

IS this valid (it is working fine) ? and how this is working ?
What i think is that, when we pass an React Element instance in createElement it detect it's type (find out the class or component) and and create Element of tha type ? so we are creating 2 React Element here ?

sorry for weak engilsh ;-(

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of an anonymous jsx function. It's not seeing the App declaration as html or javascript, instead it's being seen as jsx. Whatever transipler you're using will convert that.

For documentation see, 4th snippet down

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html

You can paste the code into the babel Repl. It converts it into the React.createlement function.

https://babeljs.io/repl/

**Edited missed a couple of bits from question**

So as noted it's transpiling the javascript to ecma 5. The jsx is being converted into [React.createlement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html). That function has several parameters.

- element type (*div, li, ul, etc.*)
- properties think class="Pretty" style="background: black;", etc. (*Note when using jsx class is referenced as className*)
- children The elements that fall under it.

In your example you have a string *Hello World* as the child. This can easily be replaced with other elements. This is the heart of jsx. You are building together a number of smaller components to form an application.

Comment: it is converted to : 
var App = React.createElement(
  "div",
  null,
  " Hello World "
);
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, null), null);

Comment: in that facebook example :-  var root = <ul className="my-list">
             <li>Text Content</li>
           </ul>;
ReactDOM.render(root, document.getElementById('example'));  and in this example var root = <ul className="my-list">
             <li>Text Content</li>
           </ul>;
ReactDOM.render(<root />, document.getElementById('example'));